# How to use foreach inside tikz fill

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I am trying to draw a filled staircase shape (shown below) generated with the code below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \tikzmath{
    \size = 3.0;    
    \n = 5;         
  }
  
  \fill[gray, draw=black, thick] 
    (0,0) -- ++(\size,0) -- 
    ++(0,\size/\n) -- ++(-\size/\n,0) --
    ++(0,\size/\n) -- ++(-\size/\n,0) --
    ++(0,\size/\n) -- ++(-\size/\n,0) --
    ++(0,\size/\n) -- ++(-\size/\n,0) --
    ++(0,\size/\n) -- ++(-\size/\n,0) --
    cycle;  

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, I would like to replace those 5 lines of `++(0,\size/\n) -- ++(-\size/\n,0) --` with a `\foreach \i in {1,...\n} {...}`, I get the error **! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.**.

```
  \fill[gray, draw=black, thick] 
    (0,0) -- ++(\size,0) -- 
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\n} {++(0,\size/\n) -- ++(-\size/\n,0) --}
    cycle;
```

Any idea how to use a `\foreach` in this case so I don't have to copy and paste those lines `\n` times?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a syntax problem when writing paths.
A `path` can be composed of `sub-paths`. In your case, it is written as a succession of `line-to` operations like this `--`.

Braces `{` allow to define `subpaths` or `scopes` which must have the same syntax as paths, i.e. the `line-to` operation (in your case) immediately followed by a `coordinate`.

`line-to operation <coordinate>` is writing like this: `-- <coordinate>`.

By placing the braces between `--` and `++<coordinate>`, the sub-path is no longer defined correctly since the `--` operation waits for a `coordinate`.  The parser sees an `brace` `{` that defines a `sub-path` as he waits for a `coordinate` and protests "***Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate***".

```
(0,0) -- ++(\size,0) -- 
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\n} {++(0,\size/\n) -- ++(-\size/\n,0) --}
```

Placing `--++` between braces works.

```
(0,0) -- ++(\size,0) 
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\n} {--++(0,\size/\n) --++(-\size/\n,0) }
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \tikzmath{
    \size = 3.0;    
    \n = 5;         
  }
  
%  \fill[gray, draw=black, thick] 
%    (0,0) -- ++(\size,0) -- 
%    ++(0,\size/\n) -- ++(-\size/\n,0) --
%    ++(0,\size/\n) -- ++(-\size/\n,0) --
%    ++(0,\size/\n) -- ++(-\size/\n,0) --
%    ++(0,\size/\n) -- ++(-\size/\n,0) --
%    ++(0,\size/\n) -- ++(-\size/\n,0) --
%    cycle;  
\fill[gray, draw=black, thick] 
    (0,0) -- ++(\size,0) 
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\n} {--++(0,\size/\n) --++(-\size/\n,0) }
    --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! I never thought about moving the -- inside the braces!

Answer (score 2):

The error may be caused by the behavior of `\fill`. Change to the command `\draw` should be OK.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzmath{
    \size = 8.0;
    \n = 8;
  }
  \draw[fill=gray, thick] (0,0) -- ++(\size,0)
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\n} { |- ++(-\size/\n, \size/\n) } -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A rough approximation

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{barcolor}{named}{gray}
\definecolor{barborder}{named}{red}

\newcommand{\barheight}{0.5cm}

\newcommand{\pyramid}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm]
        \foreach \b [count=\n] in {#1} {
            \draw [barborder,fill=barcolor]
                (0,0) rectangle (0.5*\b,\n*\barheight);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}
    \pyramid{28,20,12,6}
\end{document}
```